# Spring Boot: Return a empty JSON instead of empty body when returned object is null

Tags: json, spring, rest

I have a RestController and when I call the method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sigla/{sigla}")
@ResponseBody
public PaisDTO obterPorSigla(@PathVariable String sigla) {
    return service.obterPorSigla(sigla);
}
```

If a record is found, I get a good JSON response:

```
{"nome":"Brasil","sigla":"BR","quantidadeEstados":27}
```

but when nothing is found on database the RestController returns null and I get a empty response, completely blank body.

How can I display a empty JSON instead of a blank response? Like bellow:

```
{}
```

Complete Controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/pais")
public class PaisController {

    @Autowired
    private PaisService service;

    @RequestMapping
    public ResponseEntity<List<PaisDTO>> obterTodos() {
        return CreateResponseEntity.getResponseEntity(service.obterTodos());
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/sigla/{sigla}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes="application/json", produces="application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<PaisDTO> obterPorSigla(@PathVariable String sigla) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
        PaisDTO paisDTO = service.obterPorSigla(sigla);
        if(paisDTO != null) return new ResponseEntity<PaisDTO>(paisDTO, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        else return new ResponseEntity<PaisDTO>(headers, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: can you be more specific about what you mean by an empty JSON? the response `{}` does not make any sense.  Either the object in question has attributes (which can be blank/null) or it does not have attributes.  If it has no attributes (and hence no values) then a blank/empty body would be the correct response.  If the attributes exist but they are blank/null then initialize them as such

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, if you're using `@RestController` annotation you don't need the `@ResponseBody` annotation, get rid of that.

Second if you're trying to have REST Controller, then you're missing a few things, do it like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sigla/{sigla}", method = RequestMethod.GET, consumes = "application/json", produces="application/json")
public ResponseEntity<PaisDTO> obterPorSigla(@PathVariable String sigla) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");    
        PaisDTO paisDTO = service.obterPorSigla(sigla);
        if(paisDTO != null) return new ResponseEntity<>(paisDTO, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
        else return new ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK); 
}
```

In the example above if you'll get null then you'll return an empty response JSON.

Comment: Hi Moshe, I've tried but still getting a empty body response when null and a fine response when there's object. I will edit my question including all the Controller.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the last close bracket }

Comment: No @Moshe Arad. Not yet.

Comment: What is missing? are you trying return null or just {} empty json?

Comment: It's working now. I want to return {}. What you answered was very important, so I joined your answer with another solution and solved. Basically I used your RestController model and instead of return ResponseEntity<>(headers, HttpStatus.OK); when null, I returned a empty class (withou any attribuites or methods) annotated with @JsonSerialize.

Comment: Great, I'll appreciate if you'll mark my answer as answered and a vote up. Good Luck ;-)  @HélioMárcioFilho

Comment: Thanks @Moshe Arad. I'm in my work now, but I will answer this question showing exactly what I did. Your answer made all difference.

Comment: What do you mean by " I will answer this question" you copied my code to your question and you admit that I answered it correctly. Why don't you give my the vote up? @HélioMárcioFilho

Comment: You do not need to set the header in the response. This is already done by spring produces="application/json"

Answer (score 16):

Solution 1:
You have to implement you entity class with Serializable
Solution 2:
Your class should have getter and setter
In my case the getter and setter were given protected access modifiers. so I changed them to public and vola it worked

Comment: I was getting empty response even though there was data. After reading your answer, I realized, I forgot to add getters/setters. Thanks it worked after that

Comment: In my case I was using a `kotlin data` entity object that had private fields.  Like @priyankagoel simply removing the `private` field modifier (I opted to restrict the fields with `internal` modifier) fixed this for more, of cause with kotlin `data` generating the getters and setters for free

Answer (score 8):

The only way that I could find was to create an empty class

```java
@JsonSerialize
public class EmptyJsonBody {
}
```

Then add this to your response

```java
@PostMapping(value = "/sigla/{sigla}")
public ResponseEntity obterPorSigla(@PathVariable String sigla) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    PaisDTO paisDTO = service.obterPorSigla(sigla);
    ResponseEntity.BodyBuilder responseBuilder = ResponseEntity.ok().headers(headers);
    if(paisDTO != null) {
        return responseBuilder.body(paisDTO);
    } else {
        return responseBuilder.body(new EmptyJsonBody());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can annotate `PaisDTO` class with `@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)` annotation

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
public record PaisDTO{
...
}
```

then when you get no results you just need to instantiate PaisDTO with new `PaisDTO(null, null, null)` and Jackson will do its job and return `{}` for you