# Spring MVC enforce request empty body

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I have the following controller method for deleting some data on the server side, but I can send any value as request body which is simply ignored. Is it possible to enforce request body to be empty?

```
@DeleteMapping
ResponseEntity<?> delete(@RequestAttribute(USER_KEY) User user) {
    service.delete(user.getId());
    return ResponseEntity.ok().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

there is trick explains here [Spring Boot: Return a empty JSON instead of empty body when returned object is null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837846/spring-boot-return-a-empty-json-instead-of-empty-body-when-returned-object-is-n)

create EmptyJsonBody  and application.properties add spring.jackson.deserialization.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES=true
it will not allow any other json fields if you use EmptyJsonbody

```
ResponseEntity<?> delete(@RequestAttribute(USER_KEY) User user, @RequestBody  EmptyJsonBody   emptyBody) {
```

Comment: Well such kind of global configurations have a side effect on all other end-points.  Not preferable.

Comment: @RequestBody String body  check body is not empty will do the purpose I guess